# get hostname in parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

Is there a way to get the hostname from inside the after Find trigger in Parse Cloud code.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterFind("ProductType" , function(req,res){
    i18n.setLocaleFromSubdomain(req);
    res.success();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Depends on your implementation

1. `console.log(req);` - this will show you if the hostname is set in the request.
2. If it isn't set, you'll need to set it yourself when calling a ProductType find.

http://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/

Comment: I tried that and it's not in the req object. I am trying to read the subdomain to decide the language from android requests. using there sdk.